# Redirect_URI_missmatch: error while authenticating to the on Google Plus API with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I was follow the example here [Google+ API List with C#](http://www.daimto.com/googleplusapi-list-with-csharp/) I use this code to authenticate to  the Google plus API:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
            PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
            PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile
            };
        // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
        UserCredential credential =
            GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                {                

                    ClientId = "xxxx-jh7244ds8ruseviasg0a5g6ln09p0l44.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                    ClientSecret = "e5kjgbVJz8o92Xqb7RvpzqPk"
            },
                scopes,
                Environment.UserName,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("Daimto.GooglePlus.Auth.Store")
            ).Result;
```

When i run the code i get the following error:

[image: error image]

Even the program run on **http://localhost:53308/** Here are my settings in Google developer console.

[image]

Comment: Try enabling SSL on your project (Web Project->Properties->SSL Enabled = true), and then use those URLs for your google credentials.

Comment: the same error appear

Comment: It seems the error you are getting suggests you're redirecting to a URL that's not authorized im the console.

Answer (score 2):

When you run your code in visual stuido unless you tell it not to Visual studio is going to add random port numbers every time you run.

The redirect URI that you are sending from must exactly match the one that you have entered in Google developer console

You are currently running from

```
http://localhost:53732/authorize
```

The only redirect uri you have set up in developer console is

```
http://lostlhost:53308/sign-in
```

Fix Visual studio so that it stops adding random ports then add that one to the Developer console page

**Problem two:**

The code you are using is for installed applications not web applications.  Its going to work fine on your local machine because you have access to open the web browser.  However its not going to work when you deploy it to your webserver. You are going to have to use something more like this [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

```
private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });
```

Comment: Remember you are after redirect uri not JS origin.